# Proving the Nullstellensatz: Problem with Zariski's Lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Having problem understanding an important step in Zariski's lemma. I'm following Zariski's [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510605), and the step that I'm not getting is at the beginning of page 364 (or, well, page 3 of this particular pdf document):

> Each $\xi_i$, $i=2, 3, \dots, n$ is a root of a polynomial $f_i(X)$ taking its coefficients in $K[\xi_1]$. Let $b_i$ be the leading coefficient of $f_i (X)$, $b_i \neq 0$. If $\omega$ is any element of $R_n$, there will exist an integer $\rho$ such that the product $\omega \cdot (b_2 \dots b_n)^{\rho}$ can be expressed as a linear combination, with coefficients in $K[\xi_1]$, of the $m_2 m_3 \dots m_n$ power products $\xi_2^{j_2} \xi_3^{j_3} \dots \xi_n^{j_n}$, $0 \leq j_i \leq m_i - 1$, where $m_i$ is the degree of $f_i (X)$.

($R_n$ for the record, is how Zariski denotes $K[\xi_1 , \dots , \xi_n]$ to save space, since he uses it a lot.)

Now, I can understand the first part, why each $\xi_i$, $i=2, 3, \dots, n$ is a root of a polynomial $f_i(X)$ taking its coefficients in $K[\xi_1]$. What I cannot understand is how it from this follows that there exists a $\rho$ such that $\omega \cdot (b_2 \dots b_n)^{\rho}$ is a linear combination of the power products taking all their coefficients in $K[\xi_1]$.

Any and all help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What do you denote $R_n$?

Comment: $R_n$ is short for $K [\xi_1 , \dots , \xi_n] = K(\xi_1) [\xi_2 , \dots , \xi_n]$.

Comment: Maybe if one rephrased the question as follows it would be easier:

Comment: Let $A$ be a field, $K$ its field of fractions, and $K[a_1 , \dots , a_n]$ an algebraic extension of $K$. Since each $a_i$ is algebraic over $K$, there exists a polynomial $g_i (X) \in K[X]$ such that $g_i (a_i) = 0$. Letting $v_i$ be the product of all the denominators in $g_i$, we have a polynomial $f_i (X) = v_i g_i (X) \in A[X]$ such that $f_i (a_i) = 0$.

Comment: Let $b_i$ be the leading coefficient of $f_i$. Then, for every element $\omega \in K[a_1 , \dots , a_n]$, there exists an integer $\rho$ such that $\omega \cdot (b_1 \dots b_n)^{\rho}$ can be expressed as a sum of power products $a_1^{j_1} a_2^{j_2} \dots a_n^{j_n}$, with all coefficients being in $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where the problem in my understanding was after looking at J. S. Milne's version of the proof of Zariski's Lemma in his *A Primer of Commutative Algebra*. His proof broadly follows the line of argument used by Zariski. Anyway, the resolution looks like this:

Let $\omega$ be any element of $R_n$, which we now regard as $K[\xi_1] [\xi_2 , \dots , \xi_n]$. It is clear that for any given other element element $c \in K[\xi_1]$, for sufficiently large $N$, it holds true that $\omega c^N \in K[\xi_1] [\xi_2 , \dots , \xi_n]$. So let $c = (b_2 \dots b_n)$ where $b_i$ is defined as above. Then clearly, there exist some integer $\rho$ such that $\omega (b_2 \dots b_n)^{\rho} \in K[\xi_1] [(b_2 \dots b_n)\xi_2 , \dots , (b_2 \dots b_n) \xi_n]$. For notational economism, let's write $\beta = (b_2 \dots b_n)$ from hereon.

Now, $\omega \beta^{\rho}$ is of the form
\begin{equation*}
\omega \beta^{\rho} = \sum_{i_2 , \dots , i_n} k_{i_2 , \dots , i_n} (\beta \xi_2)^{i_2} \dots (\beta \xi_n)^{i_n}  ,
\end{equation*}
where all $k_{i_2 , \dots , i_n} \in K[\xi_1]$. We can further always "simplify it down" so that the terms of the power products $\xi_2^{i_2} \dots \xi_n^{i_n}$ don't go on increasingly further and further. Because we know that $f_i (\xi_i) = b_i \xi_i^{\deg (f_i)} + \mathcal{O} (\xi_i^{\deg (f_i)-1}) = 0$, we have $b_i \xi_i^{\deg (f_i)} = \mathcal{O} (\xi_i^{\deg (f_i)-1})$, and so since $b_i$ is a factor of $\beta$, when a term with a factor $\xi_i^{\deg (f_i)}$ appears, we can always couple it with the $b_i$ in the $\beta$ and exchange this for the $\mathcal{O} (\xi_i^{\deg (f_i)-1})$. Consequently, the only power products that we end up actually looking at are $\xi_2^{j_2} \xi_3^{j_3} \dots \xi_n^{j_n}$, where $0 \leq j_i \leq \deg(f_i) - 1$.

The problem has been resolved!